# Dynamic Table name in MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

How do I insert or create dynamic tables in MYSQL stored procedures like

```
declare @tblnm varchar(50);
set tblnm = "MyTbl";
```

create table tblnm(id int);

Answer (score -1):

Solved using Prepared Statements!